# MonoDevelop match braces weird behavior

Tags: monodevelop

Using MonoDevelop's "match braces" option, causes a weird behavior and delay.

I'll click "{" and get {|} (| = my cursor) - so far, expected.
I'll Hit ENTER and expect to get:
{
|
}

but instead i get:
{}
|

very annoying. Thing is, if I wait for a second, and then hit ENTER,
I'll get the right result:
{
|
}

anyone knows how to fix this???

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a MD bug to me (wouldn't be the first).

My best suggestion would be to turn off matching braces and type it manually. Not a big job really, but I can understand the annoyance if it breaks your routine.

Comment: Yeah. I have submitted a bug report. Hopefully this gets fixed. I agree that it isn't a big deal, just annoying... :)

Comment: I asked on the irc channel, and the answers indicates it's a bug. Too bad it messes with your workflow.